# configuring apache for osm2po

Tags: apache

I have run osm2po, and it says that I can see the output on "http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService".

However, I am running it on a Ubuntu server, and want to view the page from my desktop computer.

On the server I have opened port 8888, but I still see nothing in my desktop browser when I enter the url "http://192.168.7.66/Osm2poService". Do I need to configure apache to view this page?

Many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the `osm2po.config`:

Change

> service.domain = localhost

to

> service.domain = 192.168.7.66